# Translating a callable test into a collection membership test

Tags: python, function, collections, coding-style, argparse

What is the most elegant and pythonic way to turn a test such as:

```
def is_even(n):
  return n % 2 == 0
```

Into a logically equivalent (but different syntactically) test such as:

```
if n in even_numbers:
  # assert is_even(n)
  # ...
```

I can think of a few ways to create the object `even_numbers`, but I'm interested to hear if there are nice ways I might have overlooked.

---

<sub>*Note:* I'm aware this probably sound like an XY problem, so my use case is concerning the `choices` kwarg to `argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument`, and whether it's going to be nicer to use that or alternatively to munge the callable `type` kwarg.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn `even_numbers` into a container type:

```
class EvenNumbers(object):

    # Add other container methods as needed

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value % 2 == 0

even_numbers = EvenNumbers()
```

Then,

```
>>> 3 in even_numbers
False
>>> 4 in even_numbers
True
```